# How to specify conditions within Julia's composite types?

Tags: julia, elliptic-curve

I am trying to create a composite type in Julia representing points on an elliptic curve.
Point are valid if satisfying y^2 == x^3 + a*x + b OR both x and y are equal to nothing. Note that the later case represents point at infinity.

I have come up with the below code but can't figure out how to account for point at infinity.

- Is there a way to handle different exceptions in struct?
- Can exception simply return a valid type instead of an error? e.g. if x == nothing && y == nothing then Point(nothing,nothing,a,b)

`IntOrNothing = Union{Int,Nothing}
struct Point
    x::IntOrNothing
    y::IntOrNothing
    a::Int
    b::Int
    Point(x,y,a,b) = x == nothing || y == nothing || y^2 != x^3 + a*x + b ? error("Point is not on curve") : new(x,y,a,b)
end`

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: It doesn't accept Point(nothing,nothing,a,b) where a and b Int. In other words, error should not be raise if both x and y are equal to nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would define two inner constructors for `Point` like this:

```
IntOrNothing = Union{Int,Nothing}
struct Point
    x::IntOrNothing
    y::IntOrNothing
    a::Int
    b::Int
    Point(x::Nothing,y::Nothing,a,b) = new(x,y,a,b)
    Point(x,y,a,b) = y^2 != x^3 + a*x + b ? error("Point is not on curve") : new(x,y,a,b)
end
```

as this would be most readable in my opinion.

Note that you will get `MethodError` if you call `Point(nothing,2,1,3)` but I guess from your code you do not care about the type of exception thrown as long as it is thrown on invalid data.

Does it solve your problem?